# javac : file not found even after settinh HOME_PATH

Tags: java, javac

I have checked for the java -version and javac -version , both work , even running javac works , but when I try to run java file , saved on notepad shows javac : file not found !! I have added both the jdk and jre to the HOME_PATH too.
[image]

also if not with username..
[image]

now the file..
[image]
[image]

also the file is saved correctly i.e., its a java file with .java and not .java.txt or anything else!
[image]

also i have checked for the echo %PATH% and it does contain the java jdk ,and jre link..
[image]

Please help me solve this issue, thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're accessing file from incorrect location.

Your file seems to be in D:\ directory. See the "Location" in file properties dialog.

Comment: But if I home_path...won't it be accessible from anywhere in the system...pls correct me if am wrong

Comment: Change the directory to the loacation where your .java file is  present

Comment: Setting up the PATH variable helps you run the java commands from any location. You can not access a file if its not present in current directory. Either you need to specify full path of the file or switch to the directory containing the file.

Answer (score 1):

Change the directory to the location where your .java file is present.

Answer (score 0):

ok now i understand it!! thank you 
By setting HOME_PATH am just making it so that javac can run from any directory without  having me to set path for it again and again each time i use different directories, but to run the program , i will have to be in the same directory in which my java file is present. By set HOME_PATH  or PATH i am only skipping the step where i set path for java idk to run javac!! in that directory.